# Is it ok to manipulate static attributes on runtime?

Tags: java, static, settings, static-methods, application-settings

I am providing Settings of my JAVA project in a Prefs.java class with static attributes and static methods. But the token for OAuth2 needs to be assigned on runtime. Is this a good way to go... ?

```
public class Prefs {


  //known before runtime
  public static final String SERVER_BASE_URL ="http://api.mycompany.com/";

  //needs to be set on startup through the setter method
  private static String token;


  public static String getToken() {
    return token;
  }

  public static void setToken( String token ) {
    Prefs.token = token;
  }

  public static String getXyEndpointUrl() {
    return SERVER_BASE_URL + "/xy";

  }
}
```

Comment: The compiler will optimize it, but why not to make another final field for `XY_ENDPOINT_URL`?

Comment: Ok, then:   public static final String ENDPOINT_XY_URL = SERVER_BASE_URL + "/xy";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice against such design. This type of static variables no better than global variables. [This page](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) gives a few reasons why you should avoid them. Here are a few of them.

- Non-locality
- No Access Control or Constraint Checking
- Implicit coupling
- Concurrency issues
- Testing and Confinement

> But the token for OAuth2 needs to be assigned on runtime. Is this a good way to go... ?

Here it really seems to me like you would want to pass such token to the constructor of the Prefs object.

Comment: I am creating a library for Android which provides a high level API to our Web API. Storing the access_token to persistance isnt my job. The implementator of my lib needs to take care of it. But I havent found a suitable place to store the access token yet. I thought the easiest way for the implementator would be the Prefs-object

Comment: Prefs-object sounds good to me ;-) (Note though, that your scheme with static variables doesn't involve any Prefs-objects at all.)

Comment: Maybe I should have said Prefs-class, since it doesnt have an instance. So in this case (library for other people) u recommend to go this way? What u mean with doesn't involve any Prefs-objects?

Comment: Static (or global) variables should be avoided. Remove the static keyword and use a Prefs *object* instead. (Especially if you're writing a library!)

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are object-oriented substitutes for global variables in C.  Try to avoid them whenever possible.

Many times you only need one object, in your case it's the Prefs object.

```
public class Prefs {

  //known before runtime
  public final String SERVER_BASE_URL ="http://api.mycompany.com/";

  //needs to be set on startup through the setter method
  private String token;


  public String getToken() {
    return token;
  }

  public void setToken( String token ) {
    Prefs.token = token;
  }

  public String getXyEndpointUrl() {
    return SERVER_BASE_URL + "/xy";
  }

}

public class Program {

  protected Prefs prefs;

  protected Other prefsAware;

  public Program() {
    prefs = new Prefs();
    prefsAware = new Other(prefs);
  }

  // or even (if you don't like constructor mediated passing of prefs)
  public Prefs getPrefs() {
    return prefs;
  }

}
```

Comment: "Try to avoid them whenever possible." http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#prefer_static

Comment: There are differences between good object-oriented design and what runs fast on my platform.  Android can access static faster, but making it static will hurt maintainability.  Perhaps you're prematurely optimizing?  Odds are you're going to read this item only two or three times, and a good object-oriented design will allow you speed in the other parts of the program where it counts.  Or you could just write the whole thing in "C embedded in Java".

Answer (score 0):

typically global configs are read from properties files at runtime.  You can have varying config files for the development, QA, production environments.

The only thing you need to at least be aware of is that in a web application, if you set static variables from a web request, you could munge the data if you do not synchronize the setter.  If you are only reading then you should be fine.

An alternative to what you are doing is why not inject the OAuth key into a service that handles the authentication concerns of your system?  You could do what you need to do with a static resource, but in this case, but you should be aware that you don't really need a static variable to hold the key.

Comment: I am already overwriting a method of my HttpClient, so that the access_token gets "injected" or lets say appended to the url. However, TokenizedHttpClient.getInstance().setToken("gqwertz"); looks awful compared to Prefs.setToken("fghj"); for a implementator of my lib (also see comment to aioobe's answer)

Comment: @oneworld, yes i agree that static properties are not really a good solution for this type of thing.  But you can do it that way, and the point of the answer is to make you aware of the dangers and present an alternative.